# how is the properties set in this pom.xml?

Tags: maven, maven-3

This is the snippet of `pom.xml` from my project.

```
<properties>
        <Port>2020</Port>   
        <threads>20</threads>
        <test.suite />
        <test.suite.path />
        <useTag />
        <useTestCase />
        <args>-Dthreads=${threads} -Dtest.suite.path=${test.suite.path} -Dappenv=${test.app.env} -Dtest.suite=${test.suite} -DuseTag=${useTag} -DuseTestCase=${useTestCase}</args>
    </properties>
```

when maven build is made, I am wondering how the variables `test.suite`, `test.suite.path`, `useTestCase` are set? I do not see it anywhere in the `pom`. but the `Jenkins` build is working fine and it has substituted values for these placeholders.

what is the use of using this kind of property setting. `<variable/>` rather than `<variable>...</variable>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say exactly how those properties are set in your case we need to see the entire pom structure including the parent pom(s) as well as your Jenkins job configuration.

However, I know of two ways that these properties can be set:

1. Through a profile in one of your parent poms
2. Through system properties when maven is invoked

My guess is that you have a profile in one of your parents that sets these properties. Something like this:

```
<profile>
      <id>jenkins</id>
      <properties>
           <test.suite>...</test.suite>
           ...
      </properties>
</profile>
```

And that this profile is activated on your Jenkins server. Look [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for information how the profile can be activated.

The other option is that these properties are specified as system properties when maven is invoked from Jenkins.

As for why `<variable/>` is used over `<variable></variable>` it is a matter of taste. `<variable/>` means the same thing as `<variable></variable>` in XML.